# Macro to define a struct in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to define a struct with variable size of array. something like this:

```
#define CHAR_ARRAY(MAX_LENGTH) struct CHAR_ARRAY_#MAX_LENGTH{char data[MAX_LENGTH]; int length;};
```

so that with just the above macro, I could define different data types as follows.

```
struct Data{
CHAR_ARRAY(4) a;
CHAR_ARRAY(8) b;
};
```

Due to special requirements of existing code, plain old type defined with "struct" is required, no use of std::array, vector, etc. in particular, pointer is not accepted as our legacy code has the requirement to be plain old type, so assign or copy can be easily handled.

Comment: Can't you use a char pointer together with a size field?

Comment: Have you tried it? BTW, you're probably looking for `##`, not `#`.

Comment: In C++ you should just use `std::array<char, 4>` it has a `size()` method.

Comment: It's not a good practice in c++ and for c you can just try it... (*Hint:* `gcc -E`). "Plain old type" is a technical term used by c++ standard and I can bet you can make a compatible type using proper c++ facilities.

Comment: I tried, but the compiler does not accept.

Comment: Yes, it's possible - and no, you should not write code like this. Any use you get from generating this code using macros, can be written better, without macros (by using a std::array or std::vector instead of a native array, and by not using macros to generate code).

Comment: @pepero change `#` to `##`, and remove the `;` from the end of your `#define` line. Then it will work.

Comment: You probably want to replace that macro with a template. That's what they are for: a definition with "placeholders". `template<size_t MaxLength> struct CharArray { char data[MaxLength]; int length; };` Then use it with `CharArray<4> a` etc.

Comment: Regarding to your edit where you mention you can't use `std::array` because you need a POD type: `std::array<T, size>` is a POD if `T` is a POD.

Comment: it has std::array::size doesnt it? which means it would not be POD anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it’s possible to do that. You don’t need to name the struct at all, which makes the macro simpler:

```
#define CHAR_ARRAY(MAX_LENGTH) struct {char data[MAX_LENGTH]; int length;}
```

(Usage as in your example.)

However, I’m still not entirely clear about the purpose of this macro, since this essentially re-implements, badly, existing functionality. At the very least you should use a template instead of a macro to generate the type for you:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct char_array { char data[N]; std::size_t length; };
```

And then make the element type generic:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct array { T data[N]; std::size_t length; };
```

… and now this it’s becoming blindingly obvious that this is a bad re-implementation of `std::array`, and that there is **no** benefit in not just using the latter.

Comment: there appears to be a need for both C as well as C++.

Comment: @Richard Nothing in OP’s question/comments indicates this. Indeed, the question seems to be mis-tagged, if anything. Anyway, the macro obviously also works in C.

Comment: @RichardChambers the first 2 lines are C-compilant(they should). And since he marked it as C++ as well, why not suggest C++ answer? He never said why he cant use std::array

Comment: The only explicit requirement is a "Plain Old Data type", which got contradicted by a latter edit by banning usage of `std::array`.

Comment: You macro cannot possibly work in C because the data field has the same name for both unnamed structs.

Comment: @2501 Are you maybe confusing structs and unions here? The `data` fields are in different namespaces, even in C.

Comment: @KonradRudolph If you look at how OP uses the macros, you will notice there are multiple in the same struct, and since the structs in the struct are unnamed their member names conflict.

Comment: @2501 No, see my previous comment. There is **no** conflict.

Comment: @pepero Yes. Why not just try it?

Comment: @2501 I tried compiling it under C99 and C11 with `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra`, under both GCC and clang. I’m right.

Comment: it cannot compile on my pc.  error: expected identifier before numeric constant.  error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant.  error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ' CHAR_ARRAY' with no type [-fpermissive]

Comment: @pepero Then you’re not using the code posted here, or you have an error somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Of course you have to name the structs which makes the whole macro kinda redundant.

Comment: @2501 he also named his struct with a and b in the question

Comment: It would be better to have the length first - that way, it doesn't get overwritten when the array overruns.

Comment: thanks, Konrad, it works! there is some problem with my file usage, which reports some errors.  after correcting that, it runs! fantastic!